# Playing Background Music in Android in a Simple Game

Tags: android, media-player, android-lifecycle

I am trying to play background music in simple game on Android using `Services`.

Using the link: [Android Life Cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background/13809991#13809991)

But this code doesn't work properly, `onResumeActivity, onPauseActivity` are called but the music keep running in background even when the `onPauseActivity` method is called.

The music keeps on playing while the app is in background.

is there any other way to play background music in an Android App/Game??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class SoundGameBaseActivity extends Activity {
public static boolean isSoundPaused = false;





public static MediaPlayer mp;

protected static final String TAG = SoundGameBaseActivity.class.getName();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    playMusic();
}

public static boolean isAppWentToBg = false;

public static boolean isWindowFocused = false;

public static boolean isMenuOpened = false;

public static boolean isBackPressed = false;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart isAppWentToBg " + isAppWentToBg);

    applicationWillEnterForeground();

    super.onStart();
}

private void applicationWillEnterForeground() {
    if (isAppWentToBg) {
        //Google Analytics
        MyApp.getInstance().trackScreenView("ApplicationActivated");
        isAppWentToBg = false;
    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App is in foreground",
    //          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        playMusic();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    Log.d(TAG, "onStop ");


        applicationdidenterbackground();


}

public void applicationdidenterbackground() {

    if (!isWindowFocused) {

        isAppWentToBg = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "App is Going to Background", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        stopMusic();

    }
}

public void TurnOnMusicAgain() {

}

void playMusic() {





        if (mp == null) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.background1);
            // mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            mp.setLooping(true);

        } else {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {

            } else {
                Log.e("", "coming back");
                mp.start();
            }
        }

}

void stopMusic() {
    if (mp != null)

        mp.pause();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (this instanceof StartScreen) {

    } else {
        isBackPressed = true;
    }

    Log.d(TAG,
            "onBackPressed " + isBackPressed + ""
                    + this.getLocalClassName());
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    isWindowFocused = hasFocus;
    Log.e("Is Window Focus", "" + isWindowFocused);
    if (isBackPressed && !hasFocus) {
        isBackPressed = false;
        isWindowFocused = true;
    }

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

}

Comment: You really should not use this code as it is, I really encorage anybody reading this to have a look at what audio focus is (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus). Also MediaPlayer should be created in a background thread unless you use 'prepareAsync()'.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work for you. Add this class (Enclosed in your activity class).

```
public class BackgroundMusic extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        MediaPlayer backgroundmusic = MediaPlayer.create(YourActivity.this, R.raw.yourbackgroundmusic); 
        player.setVolume(100,100); 
        player.setLooping(true); 
        player.start(); 

        return null;
    }

}
```

And create it

```
BackgroundMusic bm = new BackgroundMusic();
```

On onResume method:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    bm.execute(null);
}
```

And onPause method:

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    bm.cancel(true);
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: onPause will be called if we move from one activity to another activity.

Comment: Yes i tried this before and it paused the music once i moved from one activity to another.